# SQL UNPIVOT for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table like this:

```
ProgramNumber   Month   EU_Date    US_Date       Japan_Date
2006060_PR       1     3/1/2017   9/1/2017        3/1/2018
2006060_PR       2     4/1/2017   9/1/2017       12/1/2017
2006060_PR       3     4/1/2017   9/1/2017       12/1/2017
2006060_PR       4     4/1/2017   9/1/2017       11/1/2017
2006060_PR       5     5/1/2017   9/1/2017       11/1/2017
```

and the desired output should be the dates spread across the months:

```
ProgramNumber   Dates        1           2        3          4         5
2006060_PR      EU_Date     3/1/2017   4/1/2017  4/1/2017  4/1/2017  5/1/2017
2006060_PR      US_Date     9/1/2017   9/1/2017  9/1/2017  9/1/2017  9/1/2017
2006060_PR      Japan_Date  3/1/2018   12/1/2017 12/1/2017 11/1/2017 11/1/2017
```

I tried this query and don't know how to further build on this.

```
select ProgramNumber, Dates, [1] from (select ProgramNumber, Month, EU_Date, US_Date, Japan_Date from dbo.TempDates ) t
unpivot (
[1] for Dates in (EU_Date, US_Date,Japan_Date)) p
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [xkcd PSA ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: Aren't you pivoting on month and unpivioting the dates?

Answer (score 2):

using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    ProgramNumber
  , Dates
  , [1] = max(case when Month = 1 then [ThisDate] end)
  , [2] = max(case when Month = 2 then [ThisDate] end) 
  , [3] = max(case when Month = 3 then [ThisDate] end)
  , [4] = max(case when Month = 4 then [ThisDate] end)
  , [5] = max(case when Month = 5 then [ThisDate] end)
from (
  select *
  from (select ProgramNumber, Month, EU_Date, US_Date, Japan_Date from dbo.TempDates ) t 
  unpivot ([ThisDate] for Dates in (EU_Date, US_Date,Japan_Date)) p
  ) u
group by ProgramNumber, Dates
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RVISN68342

returns:

```
+---------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ProgramNumber |   Dates    |     1      |     2      |     3      |     4      |     5      |
+---------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 2006060_PR    | EU_Date    | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-05 |
| 2006060_PR    | Japan_Date | 2018-01-03 | 2017-01-12 | 2017-01-12 | 2017-01-11 | 2017-01-11 |
| 2006060_PR    | US_Date    | 2017-01-09 | 2017-01-09 | 2017-01-09 | 2017-01-09 | 2017-01-09 |
+---------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I highly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

just an alternative to UNPIVOT is using CROSS/OUTER APPLY and table value constructor

```
SELECT td.ProgramNumber,
       v.Dates,
       MAX(CASE WHEN v.mon = 1 THEN v.dt END) [1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN v.mon = 2 THEN v.dt END) [2],
       MAX(CASE WHEN v.mon = 3 THEN v.dt END) [3],
       MAX(CASE WHEN v.mon = 4 THEN v.dt END) [4],
       MAX(CASE WHEN v.mon = 5 THEN v.dt END) [5]
FROM   TempDates td 
       CROSS APPLY (
          VALUES  ([Month], 'EU_Date', td.EU_Date), 
                ([Month], 'US_Date', td.US_Date), 
                ([Month], 'Japan_Date', td.Japan_Date)
       ) v(mon, Dates, dt)
GROUP BY td.ProgramNumber,
       v.Dates
```

Comment: Just seeing this post...Thank you very much!